# Why Exporting Gridview to Excel is exporting Whole Page Content?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am Working on a project where **I have to export GridView Content to xls** file..

**The Problem is it exports the whole page content instead of just GridView**.. I have looked and tried for various solutions provided online and stackoverflow too but nothing worked..

I am using **VS2012** on **Windows 8.1** and Its a **Website Project** and I have used **C#** and **MySql**.

I also used **Epplus Library** and than it worked properly on local server but when I put it Live after publishing Website, it was suppose to work but It again exported whole page Content rather than gridView on live Server.

I am not posting Code for now as I guess the problem is not regarding code but If anyone want code here I will provide..

Thanks In advance..!!

Comment: Why not export the source data instead of the GridView content: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39244538/5836671

Comment: Thanks VDWWD , thats a good suggestion but in some way I have tried that, like you suggest to create a new datatable with a raw query and than use that datatable to generate the excel file, its just that I used the same datatable that was used to generate GridView but anyway I will once try your Suggestion...

Comment: Yes, you could use the same query again or store the DataTable used for the GridView into a ViewState and use that.

Comment: @VDWWD I just tried your code with a very basic query like " SELECT * FROM my_table ". yes, the excel was downloaded but It doesn't open and shows its corrupt warning... Is there anything I am missing...??

Comment: Found a little mistake in my example. Replace these lines and Excel will not prompt that error: `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";` and `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".xlsx\"");`