# the file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension c# error when trying to open file in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

the file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension c# error when trying to open file in excel.

Here is my code:

```
private void Export2Excel(GridView GridView1, GridView GridView2)

{

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
"attachment;filename= " + filename + ".xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; //"application/vnd.ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

PrepareForExportExcel(GridView1, GridView2);


string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());


Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.OutputStream.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
lblError.Text = ex.Message;
}

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39244538/5836671, it may help you how to export a 'proper' Excel file.

Comment: What's surprising about that, exactly? The file you are writing is not an Excel file, it's just a bunch of HTML. Sure, Excel can parse it, but it *warns* you that you're not opening a real Excel file. It's a warning, not an error. You'd need to write a real OpenXML file with the correct extension (xlsx) to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 2):

This is an Excel "issue", not C#.  Excel *can* open HTML documents but it will warn you if the underlying format is different than the file extension.

The best way to solve it is to use an excel library to generate a "real" excel document other then HTML and use the right filename extension (`XLS` for binary Excel files and `XSLX` for "XML" excel files)

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you use EPPlus for example but still send `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";` instead of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml‌​.sheet` you will still get that Excel error.

Comment: @VDWWD Right, because EPPPlus writes in the Open Xml format, so the filename extension (in this case `XSLX`) must match the output type. That was the point of the "use the right extension" answer.